# Problemas al filtrar q-table quasar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar

estoy trabajando sobre un proyecto con vue js en quasar, y estoy realizando una tabla con datos y quisiera poder hacer una búsqueda de esa tabla filtrando cualquiera de los campos que están presente en ella, sin embargo cuando realizo esta acción solo filtra por algunos y no todos, aun no logro comprender la causa del problema, mi código es el siguiente:
Este es el código de mi tabla  en donde ocupo el compomente "Filter" para filtrar la tabla:

```
<div class="row classPadre">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 row">
          <q-table
            :data="proptabla.items"
            :columns="proptabla.columns"
            :row-key="proptabla.selectedkey"
            :filter="proptabla.filter"
            :selection="proptabla.selection"           
            :selected.sync="proptabla.selected"
            :visible-columns="proptabla.visibleColumns"
            :pagination="proptabla.pagination"
            :rows-per-page-options="[5,12,25,50,0]" 
             
            class="my-sticky-header-column-table row col-12 heightTable"
          >

            <template v-slot:top>
                <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12'>
                  <q-input
                    
                    borderless
                    
                    debounce="300"
                    color="primary"
                    v-model="proptabla.filter"
                    label="Buscar..."
                    class="col-12 searchStyl"
                  >
                    <template v-slot:prepend>
                      <q-icon name="search" />
                    </template>



<template  v-slot:body="props">
              <q-tr :props="props" @dblclick.native="clickDetalle(props.row)">               
                <q-checkbox size="sm" v-model="props.selected" style="padding-left:10px;"/>              
                <q-td key="rut_alumno" :props="props">
                  {{ props.row.rut_alumno }}
                </q-td>
                <q-td key="nombre_alumno" :props="props">
                  {{ props.row.nombre_alumno}}
                </q-td>
                <q-td key="carrera_nombre" :props="props">
                  {{ props.row.carrera_nombre}}
                </q-td>
                <q-td key="matricula" :props="props">
                  {{ props.row.matricula }}
                </q-td>
                <q-td key="puntaje" :props="props">
                  {{ props.row.puntaje}}
                </q-td>
                <q-td key="modulos" :props="props">
                    {{ props.row.solicitudes[0].asi_nombre}}
                </q-td>
                <q-td key="fecha_solicitud" :props="props">
                    {{ props.row.solicitudes[0].fecha_solicitud}}
                </q-td>
```

y este es el código del js de la tabla:

```
proptabla: {
            visibleColumns:['rut_alumno', 'nombre_alumno', 'carrera_nombre', 'matricula', 'puntaje', 'modulos', 'fecha_solicitud', 'estado'],
            selectedkey : "rut_alumno",
            filter: '',
            selected:[],
            selection:'multiple',
            separator:'horizontal',
            filastodos: [5, 12, 25, 0], 
            pagination:{ rowsPerPage: 12, sortBy: 'rut', descending: false },
            columns : [
                {
                  name: 'rut_alumno',
                  required: true,
                  label: 'Rut',
                  align: 'left',
                  field: row => row.name,
                  format: val => `${val}`
                },
               
                { name: 'nombre_alumno', label: 'Nombre', align: 'left', field: 'nombre_alumno', sortable: true},
                { name: 'carrera_nombre', label: 'Carrera', align: 'left', field: 'carrera_nombre', sortable: true},
                { name: 'matricula', label: 'Matrícula', align: 'left', field: 'matricula', sortable: true },
                { name: 'puntaje', label: 'Puntaje Prioridad', align: 'left', field: 'puntaje', sortable: true },
                { name: 'modulos', label: 'Módulos', align: 'left', field: 'cur_nombre', sortable: true},
                { name: 'fecha_solicitud', label: 'Fecha Actualización', align: 'left', field: 'fecha_solicitud', sortable: true},
                { name: 'estado', label: 'Estado', align: 'left', field: 'estado', sortable: true},
               
            ],
```

Ojalá puedan ayudarme ya que no logro dar con la respuesta a esta problemática